# Sending SMS using Java and AT Commands

Tags: java, at-command

I have a TC65 modem and I could not get help from anywhere. I would like to ask how to execute AT commands using Java. Once the program is written, it will be uploaded to the modem and can independently run on itself. I would like to write a code in Java that uses AT commands to send SMS.

Could anyone help me? How would I write this in Java:

number = +xxxxxxxxxx

AT+CMGS=number   /enter

(message)        /enter

I'm gonna upload this program to my GSM modem so that it sends an SMS upon power up.

```
package example.helloworld;

import javax.microedition.midlet.*;

/**
 * MIDlet with some simple text output
 */

public class HelloWorld extends MIDlet {

    /**
    * Default constructor
    */
    public HelloWorld() {
        System.out.println("Welcome");
    }

    /**
    * This is the main application entry point. Here we simply give some
    * text output and close the application immediately again.
    */
    public void startApp() throws MIDletStateChangeException {
        System.out.println("startApp");
        System.out.println("\nHello World\n");

        destroyApp(true);
    }

    /**
    * Called when the application has to be temporary paused.
    */
    public void pauseApp() {
        System.out.println("pauseApp()");
    }

    /**
    * Called when the application is destroyed. Here we must clean
    * up everything not handled by the garbage collector.
    * In this case there is nothing to clean.
    */
    public void destroyApp(boolean cond) {
        System.out.println("destroyApp(" + cond + ")");

        notifyDestroyed();    
    }
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: Define "Write this in Java", do you mean as a `String` or to a stream? Or something else entirely? Also, show us what you've already tried.

Comment: Where do I add it and how am I gonna tell it to execute the AT commands? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like that:

```
public void startApp() throws MIDletStateChangeException {
    System.out.println("startApp");

    String MyMessage = "Hello";

    ATCommand atc = new ATCommand(false); 
    atc.send("at+cmgf=1\r");
    atc.send("at+cmgs=1234567\r");
    atc.send(MyMessage + "\032\r");    // 32 = CTRL-Z

    destroyApp(true);
}
```

Note, This is TC65 stuff. Not portable.

Needed import:

```
import com.siemens.icm.io.ATCommand;
```